# Sql error using a querystring value for a database comand

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I get a SQL error with this:

```
billId = Request.QueryString["id"].AsInt();
var dbCommand = "SELECT * FROM Bill WHERE BillID=@0)";
var row = db.QuerySingle(dbCommand, billId);
```

This is the error I get

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException' occurred in System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException: There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 35,Token in error = ) ]

It's an editing page that is functional. I want to pass a value from an previous page using the query string to fill the input types on my page. I'm passing a predefined test value
through a link `href="~/Pages/Edit?id=2`

Comment: An error details might help diagnose the problem, please share it.

Comment: sorry about that i forgot to add anithing to it. i did some research on sql errors but could not find the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is a problem with your query parameters, you're using ur own query library, make sure you're setting the parameter name (@0) properly.

Check [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlcecommand.parameters%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for an example: